# phonegap-nfc - How to access to a certain memory address?

Tags: javascript, cordova, nfc, phonegap

I'm developing for the first time a NFC mobile app with Cordova and the [phonegap-nfc plugin](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc). The app should be able to get a screw turn speed.
This information is stored at the address 04 and I don't understand how I could read it, and read it periodically.